# diagonal morphism preserves properties that are satisfied by isomorphisms under base-change

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, morphism

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a property of morphisms of schemes that is fulfilled by isomorphisms.

Now assume we have a property $\mathcal{P}$ that is invariant under base-change, that means if $f:X \to Y$ satisfies $\mathcal{P}$, then for any morphism $g:Y' \to Y$ so does $f_{y'}:X_{Y'} \to Y'$.

Then why do we also have that if the diagonal morphism $\Delta_{X/Y}:X \to X \times_{Y} X$ satisfies $\mathcal{P}$, then so does the diagonal morphism after base-change, so
$\Delta_{X_{Y'} / Y'}$ ?

Our lecturer said, this was clear. But I am really struggling to use the concepts of base-change and the diagonal. So any hint would be appreciated.

My ideas:

In the beginning we have the commutative diagram:

$$\require{AMScd}$$
\begin{CD}
X\times_{Y}X @>{p_{1}}>> X\\
@VV{p_{2}}V @VV{f}V\\
X @>{f}>> Y
\end{CD}

as well as

$$\require{AMScd}$$
\begin{CD}
X_{Y'} @>{f_{y'}}>> Y'\\
@VV{p_{2}}V @VV{g}V\\
X @>{f}>> Y
\end{CD}.

But I don't know where to use the universal property of the fiber product.

Comment: You got the direction of the diagonal wrong, it is a morphism $X \to X \times_Y X$. You want to show that the diagonal $\Delta_{X_{Y'} / Y'}$ is obtained by base-change of the diagonal $\Delta_{X/Y}$.

Comment: Thank you @red_trumpet for the hint. It makes sense that the statement would follow from that. But if $\Delta_{X_{Y'}/Y}$ is obtained by a base-change, then we would have the diagram:                                       
$$\require{AMScd}$$
\begin{CD}
X_{Y'} @>{\Delta_{X_{Y'}/Y}}>> X_{Y'} \times X_{Y'}\\
@VV{}V @VV{}V\\
X @>{\Delta_{X/Y}}>> X_{Y'}
\end{CD}. But that would mean that the upper-left corner is the fiber product, or that $X_{Y'} \simeq X_{Y'} \times X_{Y'} \times X$ ? Or am I confusing something here ?

Comment: Your diagram (in the comment) doesn’t look right. I’d say that $\Delta_{X_{Y’}/Y’}$ is the base change of $\Delta_{X/Y}$ by $X_{Y’} \times_{Y’} X_{Y’} \rightarrow X\times_Y X$ (note that canonically, $X_{Y’} \times_{Y’} X_{Y’}=X\times_Y X \times_Y Y’$).